# How to find the next input with a specific name and get its value using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I need to rewrite some of my code because new DOM that is loaded through ajax is not working with my set variables.

With my code I autofill a place and streetname when zipcode and housenumber are filled in.

This is that code:

```
$("body").on("input","input[name='postcode']",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var value = $(this).val();
    var housenumber = $(this).find("input[name='huisnummer']").val();
    console.log(value);
    console.log(housenumber);
    if(housenumber.length >= 1) {
        if (value.length == 6) {
                url = 'includes/postcodecheck.php';

                var $postcode = $("input[name='postcode']").val();
                var $huisnummer = $("input[name='huisnummer']").val();

                var posting = $.post( url, { postcode: $postcode, huisnummer: $huisnummer} );
                posting.done(function( data ) {
                    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
                    var status = obj[0].status;
                    var straat = obj[0].straat;
                    var woonplaats = obj[0].woonplaats;
                    if (status == 'error') {

                    }else if(status == 'success'){
                        $('input[name="woonplaats"]').val(woonplaats);
                        $('input[name="straat"]').val(straat);
                    }
                    // var content = $( $.parseHTML(data) );
                    // $( "#postcoderesult" ).empty().append( content );
                });
        }else {

        }
    } else {
        alert('Vul eerst je huisnummer in voor dat je verder kan.');
        $("input[name='postcode']").val('');
    }
});
```

The problem is this part:

```
var housenumber = $(this).find("input[name='huisnummer']").val();
```

This is always empty, so my check if housenumber is not empty never starts. Why is that? I want to get the value of `input[name='huisnummer']` after `input[name='postcode']`.

This is my html markup:

```
<form class="editadres">
  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 pb-10">
      <label for="">Naam (bijvoorbeeld: thuis, werk etc) *</label>
      <input type="text" name="naam" value="Test123">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 pb-10">
      <label for="">Huisnummer</label>
      <input type="text" name="huisnummer" value="10" maxlength="9">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 pb-10">
      <label for="">Tussenvoegsel</label>
      <input type="text" name="tussenvoegsel" value="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 pb-10">
      <label for="">Postcode</label>
      <input type="text" name="postcode" value="3202GP" maxlength="6">
  </div>
  <div id="postcoderesult" class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 pb-10">
        <label for="">Straatnaam</label>
        <input type="text" name="straat" class="readonly1" value="Winston Churchilllaan" readonly="" required="">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12 pb-10">
        <label for="">Woonplaats</label>
        <input type="text" name="woonplaats" class="readonly1" value="Spijkenisse" readonly="" required="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Above HTML is loaded in a modal from an ajax call. I also tried to put the entire function in the ajax callback, but this has the same issue. It always starts the `alert` which means my code thinks `housenumber` does not have a length bigger than 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because `find()` searches *within* the current element to retrieve the selector you provide. As `input` elements cannot be nested this obviously cannot work.

Instead you can traverse the DOM to find the nearest common parent of both the current element and the target using `closest()`, then use `find()`. Try this:

```
var housenumber = $(this).closest('.editadres').find("input[name='huisnummer']").val();
```

That being said, if there is only ever one `"input[name='huisnummer']"` element (as is implied later in your code when you select `straat` and `woonplaats` directly, then the DOM traversal is moot and you can select housenumber directly too:

```
var housenumber = $("input[name='huisnummer']").val();
```

Comment: I originally had that, but when I loaded the HTML in a modal with data from an Ajax call it stopped working. Your top part of the answer made it work. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the use of `$(this)` which is instantiating the input element `input[name='postcode']`.

Probably what you really want is:

```
var housenumber = $("input[name='huisnummer']").val();
```

However, as I can see, you should set an Id to that element in order to maintain a cleaner markup.

```
<input type="text" name="huisnummer" id="huisnummer" value="10" maxlength="9">
                                     ^
```

That way, you can access as follow:

```
$("#huisnumber").val(); //Using Id is the fastest selection in jQuery
```